# sql count distinct by col and sum false and true

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, conditional-statements

How to query result as Expect Count with Sqlstatement

```
ID      StuId    IsDone    ExpectCount
11111   q-01     false        1         
11111   q-02     false        2      
11111   q-03     false        3        
11111   q-02     true         2   
11111   q-04     false        3   
22222   q-04     false        2
11111   q-01     true         1  
11111   q-01     true         1
```

expect if same ID StuId IsDone = true will ignore it.

```
11111 = 3
22222 = 1
```

but got

```
11111 = 1
22222 = 1
```

My query

```
SELECT ID, count(*)
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT StuId, ID, IsDone FROM Student s where IsDone = false) stu
group by ID;
```

Comment: And why do you expect 3, and not 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the expected output by changing query [as in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/6zVZCA5P).

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(DISTINCT StuId) - SUM(CASE WHEN IsDone = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ExpectedCount
FROM Student
GROUP BY ID;
```

Output :

| id | ExpectedCount |
| --- | --- |
| 11111 | 3 |
| 22222 | 1 |

Comment: i see just add distinct after sum its work correctly thanks @Tushar

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution here is to do a 2 level aggregation.  First, we can aggregate by both `ID` and `StuId` to determine which `StuId` have only false `IsDone` values.  Then we aggregate by `ID` alone to get the pure false counts.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, StuId, COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE IsDone = true) cnt
    FROM Student
    GROUP BY ID, StuId
)

SELECT ID, COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE cnt = 0) AS cnt
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```